# Before corruption, "(node)-[r:player*]->()" query was working fine, but not after importing corrupted fix data

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

some months ago my neo4j data corrupted after fixing corrupted data. I imported in neo4j. Data are working fine. All queries are working fine.

The problem is that while I search data by relationship by `*` like in

```
(node)-[r:player*]->()
```

at times, query executing continues and I am not getting any output. After some time the query goes in lock level.

before the corruption `(node)-[r:player*]->()` query was working fine. That problem occurred after importing corrupted fix data.

Comment: I tried to improve the English in the question. Please check and correct if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Can you provide the full query, for context? And is there any way to supply an upper bound? In a complex enough graph this may generate an absurd number of paths, which may explain why the query isn't returning. Do you really need every single path that matches this pattern, without any limits?